# Path not detected after HashLocationStrategy and Location Strategy Import.Angular 2 & Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

```
if (location.pathname.includes('aboutUs')) {
      this.isShow = false;
     }
```

1. Its Working fine until HashLocationStrategy and Location Strategy Import wasn't done.
2. After Import because of **#** in url it was unable to search the given path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this approach to work with `ActivatedRoute`, paths, and get url params and query params.

```
export class YourComponent {

    constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) { }

    this.activatedRoute.url.subscribe(urlSegments => {
      for (const item of urlSegments) {
        if (item.path === 'aboutUs') {
          console.log('Awesome! Path Found...');
        }
      }
    });
}
```